# Xamarin Android GCM Shutting Down VM

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When using Google Cloud Messaging on Xamarin Android the app is becoming unresponsive on register. Here is my code:

```
Thread t = new Thread (new ThreadStart (delegate {
            Console.WriteLine ("Subscribing to Push Notifications");
            try {
                var gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.GetInstance (this);
                var key = gcm.Register (new string[]{ "12345678" });
                Console.WriteLine ("Reg ID: " + key);
                gcm.Close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString ());
            }
        }));

        t.Start ();
```

If I run `gcm.Register` it freezes the app and logs:

```
Shutting down VM
```

Even weirder, is that I am getting the Registration ID successfully before it shuts down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps people in the future, I managed to fix this by deleting all the past push notification related code, and following this: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/